# iPhone, how do I create a transparent numberpad like this...?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How do I create a transparent numberpad view for a passcode view ?

Like this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buttons on this keypad are custom buttons with corresponding images and black background color and they are made semitransparent.

Comment: I'd want to show this view on top of an existing view which may have data in it, how would I transfer the content of the view underneath the buttons into the keypad view ?

Comment: Hi, if I'm getting you right, you want your background to be visible even if there are buttons or any view for that matter over it. In case of above image, I can tell you, there's an imageview with image and there are custom buttons over that image with text "1" etc and that buttons' property 'alpha' is set to something like 0.5 and buttons' background color property is set to black. You will add these buttons on the imageview underneath and you are to get the effect shown in the image. You can accomplish this all using an xib.

Comment: And instead of adding text to button, take separate labels for the text above the buttons since when you'll reduce buttons' alpha, even its text is ought to reduce its visibility.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this, it would be helpful if you could outline the steps which have been taken to produce this effect? I'm not sure if you go my meaning. What I'd like to do, is have my normal views, with a transparent numberpad over the top

Comment: 1. Take an imageview in your xib (320*480). 2. Assign an image to it. This will be your background. 3. Add a button on this imageview [for keypad button]. Change its type from rounded rect to custom. Make its alpha value to be 0.3. Set its background color to be black. 4. Add a label over this button and set its text as 1. You can also add another label for text "abc".

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a [keypad](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/KeyPad), that is configurable through a delegate.

This method

```
-(UIImage *)backgroundImageForState:(UIControlState)state 
                        forKeyAtRow:(int)row
                          andColumn:(int)column;
```

should return a transparent image.

Comment: Are you saying the code to do this is on that link to github.com ?

Comment: I am saying, that u'll find a keypadview there, which will make it easy for u, to achieve ur goal. There is also a sample delegate implementation.

Comment: vikingosegundo, you missing a file VSKeypadView.h can I have it ?

Comment: oh, they are missing? give me a moment.

Comment: I created a new Repository. see my edit. It is a complete project including some very basic artwork. the buttons are semi-transparent, but u have to add smthg in the background to be aware of it.

Comment: I've got to say I'm not that impressed with your sample, it doesn't look like normal keypad. I can see how it could the basis of one, with the right images etc.

Comment: @Jules - Not demanding at all, are you?  At least he's provided you with a starting point to do this.

Comment: @Jules: What did u expect? We are using this Code exactly as seen in ur screenshot. But i cannot give that code, as my company owns it. But it is totally possible. Just have several label and implement ur keypad delegate, that on every keystroke the next label is used.BTW: I am a programmer, not Photoshopper.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom viewController that contains all the buttons necessary, and then find a way to hook it up to a custom uiview that will intercept the input, or have a delegate for it, and intercept the input from the delegate and put the text in a uitextfield (or whatever). If you want the apple keyboard to be show, I know of only one way: have users jailbreak their iDevices and create a custom keyboard skin and put it in a Cydia repo.